# can't use Eclemma coverage tool with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jacoco, eclemma

I'm trying to use Eclemma for my project in eclipse but I get this error every time I try "coverage as"
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq3ay.jpg)

This is the error:

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/cldr/provider/CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:94)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:183)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:784)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:705)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:546)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:854)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ModuleServicesLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1078)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1301)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1386)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.<init>(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:188)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.findAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:258)
    at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2437)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1956)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1978)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3292)
    at org.junit.runner.Description.formatDisplayName(Description.java:114)
    at org.junit.runner.Description.createTestDescription(Description.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:121)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.describeChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:401)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.configureRunner(RunnerBuilder.java:81)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:72)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting sun/util/resources/cldr/provider/CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:159)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:109)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:92)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.classReaderFor(InstrSupport.java:280)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:75)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_43f5073.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:107)
    ... 51 more
```

I'm 100% sure the Date class is working fine, and I don't think the problem is with the code I wrote, but I don't know where the problem is.
I tried to reinstall eclemma but it didn't work, I still get the error.

Comment: Class file major version 59 is Java 15, looks like that code doesn't support Java 15.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted at by greg-449, I changed my version of Java from Java 15 to Java 14 (in the Eclipse Preferences window), that fixed the problem for me.